# Web Assembly - TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: c, webassembly

I'm attempting to compile a simple hello world program from C into web assembly. I've been following the guide provided by MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm). Upon navigating to the HTML page via Firefox 71 I receive a `TypeError: “NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.”` error.

Here's the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
```

And the command used to compile:

```
emcc hello.c -s WASM=1 -o hello.html
```

Am I missing something? Has anyone else encountered this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue and I tried a few solutions, these seem to work:

(1) See if the `emrun` webserver can run the file via:

```
emrun --no_browser --port 8080 .
```

(and open the site in your browser, i.e. `localhost:8080`)

(2) If not, then try using this `git` repo for `emsdk` :

```
git clone https://github.com/juj/emsdk.git
cd emsdk
./emsdk install latest
./emsdk activate latest
source ./emsdk_env.sh
```

And then try `emrun` as in method (1).

CORS is enabled and that prevents the `.wasm` file from being downloaded. So running a small server to access the `html` files works (this includes a simple python server via `python3 -m http.server` !)

This is also mentioned in the developer guide:

> Finally, to actually run the program, we cannot simply open the HTML
>   file in a web browser because cross-origin requests are not supported
>   for the file protocol scheme. We have to actually serve the output
>   files over HTTP.

You can refer all this information from here: https://webassembly.org/getting-started/developers-guide/

Comment: Both emrun and the minimal python server solutions work. Seems like the only way to serve WASM is through a web server.

Comment: Correct, the developer docs says the following: `Finally, to actually run the program, we cannot simply open the HTML file in a web browser because cross-origin requests are not supported for the file protocol scheme. We have to actually serve the output files over HTTP.`